# Recursive enumeration through each cell of a matrix in C

Tags: c, recursion, matrix

I want to fill a 3x3 matrix with all possible combinations where each cell can take 0 or 1 or 2. Also I want to print the matrix for different combinations. So, the code should print 3^9=19683 different matrices.
For example I want to print

```
   0 1 2 
   0 0 1 
   2 0 1
```

---

```
   0 1 2 
   0 1 0 
   0 0 2
```

and so on.

Here's what I have tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int mat[3][3];
int row, col;

int matrixfill(int row, int col) {
    int i, k, l;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
         mat[row][col] = i;

         if (row < 2 && col < 2) {
             col++;
             matrixfill(row, col);
         } else
         if (row < 2 && col == 2) {
             col = 0;
             row++;
             matrixfill(row, col);
         } else
         if (row == 2 && col < 2) {
             col++;
             matrixfill(row, col);
         } else {
             for (k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                 for (l = 0; l < 3; l++) {
                     printf("%d ", mat[k][l]);
                 }
                 printf("\n");
             }
             printf("\n---------------\n");
         }
     }
 }

 int main() {
     matrixfill(0,0);
 }
```

The last matrix it prints is

```
      0 1 2 
      0 1 2 
      0 1 2
```

But I expected to see the last matrix

```
      2 2 2
      2 2 2
      2 2 2
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What should be the first and second matrices? Your example would require the use of `rand()`?

Comment: I don't care about the 1st and last matrix. I just want to print all possible combinations of the matrix where each cell can go from 0 to 2. In the example I showed two such matrices, not necessarily the 1st and 2nd. The last matrix I expect to see that according to my code but again it doesn't have to be that one.

Comment: Does it really have to solved by recursion (heavy on stack), or would a pair of nested loops do? After all, the recursive function does have one loop.

Comment: I know with nested loops it would be easier but I am looking for a recursive solution please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution dos not work because you modify `row` and `col` in the loop.  You do not test every possibility for cell `mat[row][col]` before recursing on the next cell.

You can make a simple recursive solution this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int mat[3][3];

void matrixfill(int n) {
    int col, row, i;
    if (n == 9) {
        // print the matrix
        for (row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
            for (col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
                printf("%d ", mat[row][col]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n---------------\n");
    } else {
        // enumerate all possible contents for cell n and recurse
        row = n / 3;
        col = n % 3;
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            mat[row][col] = i;
            matrixfill(n + 1);
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    matrixfill(0);
    return 0;
}
```